# Probability Theory: Random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The question reads:

" A standard deck of 52 cards is shuffled and dealt.$X_{1}$ be the number of cards appearing before the first ace and $X_{2}$ be the number of cards between first and second ace (not counting either ace). Find the probability of $P(X_{2} = 10 | X_{1} = 15)$".

My attempt is to use conditional probability formula: $P(X_{2} = 10 | X_{1} = 15) = \frac{P(X_{2}= 10, X_{1} = 15)}{P(X_{1} = 15)}$

I was about to find the denominator of this by: 
$P(X_{1} = 15) = \{ \text{ drawing 15 cards and the 16th will be the first ace} \} = \frac{48}{52} \times ...\times \frac{33}{37} \times \frac{4}{36}$.

How can I find the numerator where there are 15 cards before the first ace and 10 cards between first and second ace?

Comment: You're doing fine so far; just keep going.  What is the probability that the seventeenth card is not an Ace?  The eighteenth? and so on.

Comment: So what I understand the wording of event $\{ X_{1} = 15, X_{2} = 10 \}$. Drawing 15 cards other than ace and the 16th will be the first ace, then from 17th to 26th will be cards different than ace and the 27th card will be the second ace.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

You've already got a start on the numerator! Think about what it means:

$P(X_2 = 10, X_1 = 15)$ = the probability that $X_2$ is 10 and $X_1$ is 15. In other words, the probability that you draw 15 cards before the first ace, THEN 10 cards before the second.

$P(X_2 = 10, X_1 = 15) = \frac{48}{52} \times ...\times \frac{33}{37} \times \frac{4}{36} \times \frac{32}{35} \times ...$

Comment: Thank you very much!! that is what I understand the wording of this event is going to be. I was confused by the phrase (not counting either ace) at first, but I think I understand it more now.